# Changing name of Message Part element

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a WCF service as shown below. It generates the following WSDL.

Based on the naming conventions in the organization, I need the **element** name to be "tns:GetDataUsingDataContractInput" instead of ="tns:GetDataUsingDataContract" (i.e, the word “Input” need to be appended. )

How can we do it using C# Code? Also, the corresponding xsd generated should reflect this change.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

WSDL

[image]

**REFERENCE**

1. Understanding WSDL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but could it be as simple as doing:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract(Name="GetDataUsingDataContractInput")]   
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The challenge is  now the output response has an unwanted word "input" - GetDataUsingDataContractInputResponse. How to overcome this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure how you would create different Input and Output Messages. Hopefully someone else will chime in, I'd be interested if there is a viable solution. Good luck!

Comment: Create a MessageContract for the input and one for the output of the service. You can then change their attribute name to do what you want.